# Multiselect defaulting checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using this multiselect library

https://github.com/ehynds/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget

For some reason by default when I open the select the first option is selected.  How can I make them unselected by default?

```
$("select").multiselect();
```

Here is function I use to populate select element:

```
populateSelect : function() {
    var statusHtml = $('select');
    statusHtml.html(" ");

    $.each(statusArr, function(index, value) {
        statusHtml.append($('<option value=' + value + '>' + statMap.attr(value) + '</option>'));
    });

    $("select").multiselect({
        noneSelectedText: 'Hello',
        selectedText: 'Hello',
    });                                         
},
```

Comment: Can you post more of the code that you are using? Including html

Comment: added additional javascript

Answer (score 0):

Working here [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x678zhpk/)

There might be a better way to do this, but after

```
$("select").multiselect({
    noneSelectedText: 'Hello',
    selectedText: 'Hello',
});
```

Put these lines to set the value to null and then refresh the multiselect element.

```
statusHtml.val(null);
statusHtml.multiselect("refresh");
```